# How to select specific row column pairs in numpy array which have specific value?

Tags: arrays, numpy, random, indexing, extract

I am trying to have a numpy array with random numbers from 0 to 1:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random((3,3))
```

yields

```
[[ 0.11874238  0.71885484  0.33656161]
 [ 0.69432263  0.25234083  0.66118676]
 [ 0.77542651  0.71230397  0.76212491]]
```

And, from this array, I need the row,column combinations which have values bigger than 0.3. So the expected output should look like:

```
(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)
```

To be able to extract the `item` (the values of x[row][column]),and tried to write the output to a file. I tried the following command:

```
with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as fd:
    for row in x:
        for item in row:
            if item > 0.3:
                print(item)
                for row in item:
                    for col in item:
                        print(row,column,'\n')
                        fd.write(row,column,'\n')
```

However, it raises an error :

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Also, I searched but could not find how to start the numpy index from 1 instead of 0. For example, the expected output would look like this:

```
 (1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)
```

Do you know how to get these outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the indices along first two axes that match that criteria with `np.nonzero/np.where` on the mask of comparisons and then simply index with [`integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing) -

```
r,c = np.nonzero(x>0.3)
out = x[r,c]
```

If you are looking to get those indices a list of tuples, `zip` those indices -

```
zip(r,c)
```

To get those starting from `1`, add `1` and then zip -

```
zip(r+1,c+1)
```

On `Python 3.x`, you would need to wrap it with `list()` : `list(zip(r,c))` and `list(zip(r+1,c+1))`.

Sample run -

```
In [9]: x
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.11874238,  0.71885484,  0.33656161],
       [ 0.69432263,  0.25234083,  0.66118676],
       [ 0.77542651,  0.71230397,  0.76212491]])

In [10]: r,c = np.nonzero(x>0.3)

In [14]: zip(r,c)
Out[14]: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

In [18]: zip(r+1,c+1)
Out[18]: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]

In [13]: x[r,c]
Out[13]: 
array([ 0.71885484,  0.33656161,  0.69432263,  0.66118676,  0.77542651,
        0.71230397,  0.76212491])
```

Writing `indices` to file -

Use `np.savetxt` with `int` format, like so -

```
In [69]: np.savetxt("output.txt", np.argwhere(x>0.3), fmt="%d", comments='')

In [70]: !cat output.txt
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2
2 0
2 1
2 2
```

With the `1` based indexing, add `1` to `np.argwhere` output -

```
In [71]: np.savetxt("output.txt", np.argwhere(x>0.3)+1, fmt="%d", comments='')

In [72]: !cat output.txt
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when I use zip(r,c), it makes a zip object at memory. How can I print them out to a file?

Comment: @podedo I guess if you are on Python 3.x, you would need `list(zip(r,c))`. About printing to a file, I am not sure really.

Comment: @podedo Added section on writing to text file. Check that out!

Answer (score 1):

You could use np.where, which returns two arrays (when applied to a 2D array), with indices of rows (and corresponding columns) satisfy the condition you specifiy as an argument.
Then you can zip these two arrays to get back a list of tuples:

```
list(zip(*np.where(x > 0.3)))
```

If you want to add 1 to every element of every tuple (use 1 based indexing), either loop over the tuples, either add 1 to each array returned by where:

```
res = np.where(x > 0.3)
res[0] += 1  # adds one to every element of res[0] thanks to broadcasting
res[1] += 1
list(zip(*res))
```

Comment: It is very clean! Thank you. But how can add +1 to each tuple?